# Как передать элементы из списка в аргументы метода?

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность

Вот фрагмент кода:

```
sitelist = ["https://www.12amrun.com","https://www.abovethecloudsstore.com","https://www.addictmiami.com",]

def connect():
    req = requests.get('как сюда поместить i-ый объект из sitelist, чтобы функция connect() прошлась в нескольких процессах по элементу из списка?')

def enter():
    pool = ThreadPool(3)
    results = pool.map(connect(), sitelist)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

enter()
```

Нужно вызвать функцию `enter()`, которая будет в нескольких процессах выполнять функцию `connect()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool


sitelist = [
    "https://www.12amrun.com",
    "https://www.abovethecloudsstore.com",
    "https://www.addictmiami.com"
]

def connect(url):
    rs = requests.get(url)
    print(rs)
    return rs

def enter():
    with ThreadPool(3) as pool:
        results = pool.map(connect, sitelist)
        print(results)

enter()
```

Comment: Раз уж тронули этот вопрос-ответ, может стоит переписать модно-современно на `with pool`? )

Comment: @CrazyElf, справедливо :)